# How to get all users from aweber list in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net, list, aweber

I am developing web application (using VS2010 and asp.net,c#) that gets all aweber users list. I am using following code to achieve it.

i am using [this](http://aweber.codeplex.com/documentation) useful document. as per this document i did following things..

1. created account in aweber labs https://labs.aweber.com/
2. created "test" app
3. Use the "consumerKey" and "consumerSecret" code which is given by aweber team.
4. used following code

   ```
   String consumerKey = "Afdgdfgdgfgdfll";
   String consumerSecret = "zDKexfgdfgdfQqlKh5KD";
   API api = new API(consumerKey, consumerSecret);
   api.CallbackUrl = "http://" + Request.Url.Host + ":" + Request.Url.Port + "/Authorize.aspx";
   api.get_request_token();
   HttpContext.Current.Session.Add("oauth_token", api.OAuthToken);
   HttpContext.Current.Session.Add("oauth_token_secret", api.OAuthTokenSecret);
   api.authorize();
   ```

i am getting null value "OAuthToken". If any solution then let me guide.

Thanks in advance. !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out http://aweber.codeplex.com/

This will save you a lot of work.

Comment: Hi Adam, thanks for you response. but i am getting error on `api.authorize()`... it will redirect me to `https://auth.aweber.com/1.0/oauth/authorize?oauth_token=Aqnfdgjlgdfgfdgdfgjk` this link. when i am trying to login with my **labs developers** account, it will give me "Notice: Invalid credentials - please retry". So, it asking for which login details ? ? so then, i needs a `regular Aweber account` ? Or is there any other ways to do it ??

Comment: You need to use a regular Aweber account, not the developer account.

Comment: can we use this url `https://api.aweber.com/1.0/accounts/<id>/lists/<id>/subscribers` to get subscribers list ? i found it on this labs reference doc https://labs.aweber.com/docs/reference/1.0#subscribers

Comment: Adam, ohh so we must need a reguler Aweber account. so we need to add details of that account and needs to use that account login details ??

Comment: The url can be used to pull subscribers, however you need to use your regular Aweber credentials to login for these types of actions.